# runtime for openmp as a function of number of threads is increasing

Tags: c, amazon-ec2, openmp

I have a c program that is running a loop and timing it's runtime. To see speedup, I change the number of threads in my main with `omp_set_num_threads` and then call the functions.

```
int main(){
      ...
      for(int num_threads = 1; num_threads<=16; num_threads *= 2)
      {
        omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);
        pFilterFirst ( ..., num_threads );
        checkData ( serial_array, output_array );
        memset ( output_array, 0, DATA_LEN );

        pDataFirst ( ..., num_threads );
        checkData ( serial_array, output_array );
        memset ( output_array, 0, DATA_LEN );
      }
    }



int pDataFirst(..., num_threads) {
    /* Variables for timing */
  struct timeval ta, tb, tresult;

  /* get initial time */
  gettimeofday ( &ta, NULL );

  #pragma omp parallel for

  /* for all elements in the data */
  for (int x=0; x<data_len; x++) {
    /* for all elements in the filter */
    for (int y=0; y<filter_len; y++) {
      /* it the data element matches the filter */
      if (input_array[x] == filter_list[y]) {
        /* include it in the output */
        output_array[x] = input_array[x];
      }
    }
  }


  /* get initial time */
  gettimeofday ( &tb, NULL );

  timeval_subtract ( &tresult, &tb, &ta );

  printf ("Parallel data first took %lu seconds and %lu microseconds.  Filter l\
ength = %d. Threads = %d\n", tresult.tv_sec, tresult.tv_usec, filter_len, num_t\
hreads );
}
```

When I look at the runtime as a function of number of threads, the runtime increased as the number of threads increased, which makes no sense. I am running this on an amazon ec2 instance.

---

so it seems that the problem was fixed when I ran the simulations on large ec2 instances. i'm getting the speedup I expect.

Comment: Your computation will benefit from parallelization if it runs on multiple *physical* cores and `data_len` is large enough.  Otherwise, the setup, teardown, and context switching costs associated with parallelizing the computation will overcome the time savings from running several parts simultaneously (if that even happens).  It's unclear how your ec2 instance is provisioned, but I can easily believe that parallelizing this particular computation yields a net performance loss.

Comment: aside from the computation, is there something wrong with how im declaring the number of threads?

Comment: I'm not expert in OMP specifically, but your use of `omp_set_num_threads()` appears reasonable and consistent with its docs.

Comment: I would, however, suggest `clock_gettime()` for your timer instead of obsolete `gettimeofday()`.

Comment: In any event, if using multiple threads slows down the program then there is a good solution: don't use multiple threads.

Comment: I don't know how big your `input_array` and `filter_list` are, but this problem is very much memory bound and no reasonable speedup is to be expected unless at least `filter_array` fits the CPU caches.

Comment: what were your compiler options? Did you use optimization (`-O3`)?  Did you look at warnings (`-Wall`)?